# AddThis integration with GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, addthis

I managed to make `AddThis` work with my GWT app, however there is a problem that when user navigate to other place in the web app, then hit the Back button, the AddThis widget is not rendered back.

I use this wrapper: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-addthis/

For example the AddThis widget is rendered in `#page1` then user navigates to `#page2` then hit back to `#page1`, the `AddThis` widget is not there anymore.

What could I be missing?

Comment: What's the URL where you're seeing this issue?

Comment: @Paul in my GWT app running on localhost

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help unless you have an example page where I can see it running. I'm not familiar with this plugin so I can't say what it's doing. It's not an official AddThis product.